# Подключение на сокетах между PHP и C++

Tags: php, c++, сервер, сокет, client

Я пытаюсь создать подключение между приложением написанным на С++ и сервером IIS на сокетах, чтобы можно было обмениваться сообщениями с сервером в реальном времени.
На данный момент я установил Windows Server 2019 на виртуальную машину, подключил PHP и написал вот такой скрипт:

```
<?php
$port = 7777;
$address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if ($socket === false) {
   echo "Ошибка при создании сокета: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}
$result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $port);
if ($result === false) {
  echo "Ошибка при подключении: ($result) ".socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket))."\n";
}

$in = "Hello from PHP!";
socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in));
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

И такой код приложения C++:

```
WSAData wsaData;
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 1), &wsaData);

SOCKADDR_IN addr;
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
addr.sin_port = htons(7777);


SOCKET sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
listen(sListen, SOMAXCONN);

SOCKET newConnection;
int sizeofaddr = sizeof(addr);
newConnection = accept(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &sizeofaddr);
if (newConnection)
{
    cout << "User connected" << endl;
    char Message[256];
    ZeroMemory(Message, 256);
    recv(newConnection, Message, 256, 0);
    cout << Message << endl;
}
```

Теперь я делаю такие действия: запускаю приложение и запускаю PHP скрипт, приложение выводит в консоль сообщение "Hello from PHP!", но я знаю что когда я поставлю этот код на VDS он работать скорее всего не будет, так как в качестве сервера выходит именно приложение а не сервер, я хочу сделать это но совсем не понимаю как, очень надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Возможно есть более правильные варианты сделать это не используя PHP?

UPD:

Сделал всё наоборот, но подключения к сожалению нет.

```
<?php
$port = 7777;
$address = '0.0.0.0';

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if ($socket === false) {
    echo "1: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}
if(!socket_bind($socket, $address, $port))
{
    echo "2: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}
socket_listen($socket);
$client = socket_accept($socket);
echo "User connected!";
$in = "Hello from PHP!";
socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in));
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

C++

```
    WSAData wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.2");
    addr.sin_port = htons(7777);
    SOCKET Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    connect(Socket, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    cout << "Connected." << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
```

Comment: ¿А что мешает сделать наоборот?

Comment: @user7860670 я обновил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: *"подключения к сожалению нет"* - ¿почему вы так решили? Результат `connect` на стороне C++ вообще игнорируется...

Comment: в PHP нет вывода "User connected!", в приложении в свою очередь нет вывода "Connected."

Comment: Но если я запущу приложение на Windows Server, то подключение устанавливается

Comment: ¿А адрес сервера правильный? ¿Порт на нем открыт?

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, я вижу Ваш вопрос про взимодействие PHP и клиента, написанного на C++, второй раз.

Я стараюсь избегать категорических утвержедний, но, мне кажется, Ваши проблемы происходят из за непонимания того, как работает "жизненный цикл PHP страницы".

Уделите 2 минуты пониманию следующих фактов:

1. PHP с самого начала своего существоавания ориентировалось на HTTP - взаимодействие без установления соединения. То есть "запрос-ответ". То есть, жизненным принципом работы PHP страницы всегда было "*выдай ответ и умри!*", и функция die() своим названием как бы намекает на это.

Почему это так? По историческим причинам. Чтобы экономить ресурсы сервера - первые версии PHP были "прикручены" через CGI и на каждый запрос создавали процесс. Это очень ресурсоёмко с точки зрения OS.

Потом наступили благословенные времена Apache, FastCGI (FPM) и появления в PHP сессий... Но Вам интересно несколько другое.

2. Пускай у Вас есть страница на WEB - сервере. и есть Ваш клиент на Вашей машине. Который должен бы к этой странице "приконнектиться".

Рассмотрим момент времени до того, как вы открыли эту стрраницу в браузере. *Есть ли в этот момент куда коннектиться Вашему клинету?* Нет. Страницу то еще не вызвали.

Ок. Теперь вы отрываете в бразуере страницу, она вам что то отвечает, Вы переключаетесь на клиента... Тот же вопрос: *Есть ли в этот момент куда коннектиться Вашему клинету?* - Уже нет. в соответсвии с идеологией страница ответила Вам что то и умерла.

Это - *упрощенное* объяснение, которое, тем не менее, показывает общую картину.

3. Можно ли с этим бороться? - теперь, когда Вы знаете, в чем проблема - да, можно. Можно "зациклить" страницу на WEB -сервере так, чтобы она "не умерла, а осталась жить довольно долгое время".

В Вашем коде, когда вы говорите listen() - именно это и происходит, управление передаётся OS, и венется в скрипт, когда произойдёт подключение.

4. Вообще говоря, вы боретесь даже не с PHP, а с web-сервером. Ведь есть [способы](http://codinghamster.info/php/konsolnoe-prilozhenie-na-php/) запуска PHP-скрипта как процесса, из консоли. Он будет висеть в памяти до тех пор, пока его кто нибудь не пристрелит.
5. Чтобы делать такие штуки на хостинге, Вам надо перестать использовать то, что называется WEB хостинг и начать использовать то, что называется VPS-хостинг. Это такой хостинг, где у вас у провайдера маленький линукс, к которому есть консоль. А если есть консоль - то можно не только PHP скрипты там запускать, а запустить просто любое приложение. Например, если Вы знаете C++ - написать на C++ и клиента, и сервер.
6. Вообще говоря, Вы пытаетесь использовать технологию, которая просто не очень походит для Ваших целей. Вот сделаете Вы одного клиента с одной PHP-страницей. А потом захотите, чтобы клиентов было больше одного. И в этом месте Вам придётся бороться уже c однопоточностью PHP.

Comment: В вопросе я написал что использую локальный VDS сервер для тестирования, а ещё обязательным условием является операционная система Windows.

Comment: Замечательно. Тогда вернёмся к Вашему вопросу: "но я знаю что когда я поставлю этот код на VDS он работать скорее всего не будет". Давайте поиграем в игру на диагностику: создадим ситуацию, когда только один компонент системы может не работать. Проверим: HTTP порт открыт? Для этого надо создать на VPS статическую страницу и открыть её в браузере на домашнем ПК. Потом проверим: а порт 7777 открыт? Для этого возьмем программу hfs.exe (локальный веб-сервер для винды) и повесим её на порт 7777. Откроем страницу в браузере. Ну и так далее, по одному потенциально неработающему компоненту.